# How to unmarshal json with unknown field and key

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

From front-end I got this example of json:

```json
{
  "properties":{"unknown key": "unknown value","unknown key2": "unknown value 2"}
}
```

I start to parse it with map[string]interface{} but it doesn't work. Also I don't know how much this fields I can got. It can be 10 or 1.

Code:

```golang
type test struct {
    p map[string]string `json:"properties"`
}

func main() {
    var t test

    body := `
    {
        "properties":{"unknown key": "unknown value","unknown key2": "unknown value 2"}
    }
    `

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &t)

    fmt.Println(t.p)
}
```

This code always return an empty map.

Comment: *it doesn't work.* What exactly happens? => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It doesn't work because you did the mistake that is asked twice a week on SO and explained in any totorial or documentation about json marshaling in Go.

Comment: Thank for your feedback I will try to avoid situation like that in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export the field of the struct that should be Unmarshalled, like:

```
type test struct {
    P map[string]string `json:"properties"`
}
```

See https://go.dev/play/p/Fp91DTlrZpw

Comment: What a stupid mistake from me. Thank you!